# Create thread in suspended mode using pthreads

Tags: c, linux, winapi, pthreads

In Win32, you can create a thread in suspended mode, by using the *dwCreationFlags* parameter with CREATE_SUSPENDED. I am looking for a similar functionality with pthreads. Note that I don't want to suspend the thread after running it and then pausing it by using condition variables, but actually create it in suspended mode and then start it later on.

The advantage of using this approach is that I can assign some properties to that thread before running it. For example, bind it to a certain core before starting, which is more efficient than first starting and then assigning it to a core, as it might get moved from one core to another.

If not possible, can we at least bind a thread to a core when calling **pthread_create**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to bind a thread to a CPU right from the start, you can use the form of `pthread_create` with a `pthread_attr_t` argument. Linux suports a special attribute [pthread_attr_setaffinity_np](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_attr_setaffinity_np.3.html), which allows the binding of a thread to a certain CPU set. Do not confuse this with `pthread_setaffinity_np` which requires an already running thread.

The plan of action is this:

```
// create generic attribute set
pthread_attr_t attr;
pthread_attr_init(&attr);

// enhance with CPU set
pthread_attr_setaffinity_np(&attr, ...cpuset-args);

// create thread with right attributes including CPU set
pthread_t thread;
pthread_create(&thread, &attr, ...);

// viola, thread runns on given CPU-set, cleanup
pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
```

Comment: This answer is unrelated to the original authors question.

Comment: @bkausbk Nevertheless it solved the original authors problem.

Answer (score 0):

Initial suspended state or core binding would be handled by attributes given in the second argument of pthread_create, with the options documented in `pthread_attr_init`'s manpage. I haven't found relevant flags there, so it seems to be currently not possible. You could file a bug against the Linux pthreads implementation.

Comment: [pthread_attr_setaffinity_np()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_attr_setaffinity_np.3.html) might be useful.

Comment: pthread_attr_setaffinity_np() can only bind after pthread_create.

Comment: @MetallicPriest: I have written my own answer, please check regarding your objection.

Answer (score 0):

There are no flags currently on pthread attributes to create a thread in suspended state.

It is likely that you have to suspend it manually after creation.

For implementing suspending/resume, you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140867/suspend-pthreads-without-using-condition)

Comment: At least, can we bind it to a core at pthread_create time? By the way, I hate that condition variable method to suspend, so inefficient!

Comment: you're looking for this [function](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html)