# Shutting a Java application programmatically and restarting it again with different VM Arguments

Tags: java, python, jvm, jvm-arguments

I have a Java application (say X) whose performance (time taken to run the application) has to be logged in a text file along with the specified VM Arguments. Performance of my application will vary as we change the maximum Heap Size.
So, my requirement is to start the application X from another program (java or python or shell script) with one set of VM argument(say Xmx50M), perform the operations, log the time, shut it down and then perform the same set of operations with a different VM argument. I have to do this multiple times for multiple VM arguments.
I am not sure how can I do this.
I have read various threads here and blogs but couldn't find anything which could let me shut and then restart the application with different set of VM arguments.
I have also tried using shutdown hooks but that didn't help. I guess I am doing something wrong in the usage.

```
public static void restartApplication() throws IOException {
    try {
        String java = System.getProperty("java.home") + "/bin/java";
        List<String> vmArguments = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean()
                .getInputArguments();
        StringBuffer vmArgsOneLine = new StringBuffer();
        for (String arg : vmArguments) {
            if (!arg.contains("-agentlib")) {
                vmArgsOneLine.append(arg);
                vmArgsOneLine.append(" ");
            }
        }
        final StringBuffer cmd = new StringBuffer("\"" + java + "\" "
                + vmArgsOneLine);
        String[] mainCommand = System.getProperty("sun.java.command")
                .split(" ");
        if (mainCommand[0].endsWith(".jar")) {
            cmd.append("-jar " + new File(mainCommand[0]).getPath());
        } else {
            cmd.append("-cp \"" + System.getProperty("java.class.path")
                    + "\" " + mainCommand[0]);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < mainCommand.length; i++) {
            cmd.append(" ");
            cmd.append(mainCommand[i]);
        }
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd.toString());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IOException(
                "Error while trying to restart the application", e);
    }
```

Comment: I suggest you try a bash script. You'll want to launch it from the script and make note of the PID. You can then send a kill to it (via its PID), then restart with different VM args.

Comment: I think you should consider adding signal handling to your Java application and, to shut it down, simply send a specific signal that your application is prepared to handle to cause a graceful shutdown. That way, you can iterate over your arguments, send a signal to the java program to cause it to shut down, and then re-launch the new instance. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409165/signal-handling-using-term) might be useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Debugger: Is it possible selectively suspend threads?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137293/java-debugger-is-it-possible-selectively-suspend-threads)