# How to cause arbitrary sleeps for C program at runtime

Tags: c, debugging, testing, pthreads, distributed-computing

Is there a way to make threads executing a C program to sleep at arbitrary points of execution?

I'm interested of testing the robustness of an implementation of distributed algorithm and I'd like to run different scenarios repeatedly so that threads would be suspended randomly.

(Adding sleeps to the code is not what I'm looking for.)

Thanks!

Comment: Send it a signal and `sleep` in the signal handler. That will give you arbitrary *times* when sleep occurs but not sure whether that's what you mean or you need to control the exact line of code where it sleeps.

Comment: Maybe try writing a gdb script to have it pause execution at random times, for random amounts of time, and then continue.

Comment: The idea is to have unpredictable sleeps. I found actually a promising answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397068/how-to-pause-a-pthread-any-time-i-want and it's based on user-defined signals.

Comment: Have you thought of randomly locking a mutex (or semaphore, depending on the case)?

Comment: @Leonardo Araujo yes, that's what I currently have but its limited to mutexing only. I want random slowness, and record added sleeps for each test run so that it can be repeated in case of test failure.

Comment: [`kill()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/kill.html) and [`signal()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html) perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to run different scenarios repeatedly so that threads would be suspended randomly.

One way to achieve this (on a UNIX system) is to run the program under a debugger, which can suspend and resume threads at arbitrary points in time.

Debugger here doesn't mean GDB -- it could be any program utilizing `ptrace` to control the target.

Unfortunately writing such a control program / debugger from scratch is quite involved -- you'll need to implement a lot of low-level thread tracking.

Since you control the *target* program, you can cheat by making it create all the threads, then block them all before doing any work. Now the *debugger* program can attach all the threads, unblock them, and start suspending them at random.

Another alternative is to modify an existing debugger to do your bidding. This would be hard to do with GDB, but is *probably* easier with LLDB.