# Task Activation VxWorks vs. Posix

Tags: pthreads, vxworks

I am activating the tasks in VxWorks via `taskActivate(TaskID)` systemcall and suspending via `taskSuspend(TaskID)`. For Linux, I am using Posix threads and I could not find any equivalent systemcalls which I want to use to start, suspend or resume the threads.

How can I activate, resume or suspend the tasks in Posix?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In POSIX, threads are used instead of tasks and there are no methods that can be used to suspend a thread, it wasn't included in the standard since it can cause deadlocks and other issues.

Instead, have a look at using semaphores and/or mutexes with conditional variables to synchronize tasks.

This question and answer was a very helpful resource for me: [What is the best solution to pause and resume pthreads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662689/what-is-the-best-solution-to-pause-and-resume-pthreads)